# Include udt: in the XML tag

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

Using SQL query I need to get data as like below.

```
<AcceptanceDateTime>
  <udt:DateTimeString formatCode="304">20161207010101Z</udt:DateTimeString>
</AcceptanceDateTime>
```

I tried to generate it using the below SQL query,but it throws error

```
begin tran
    SELECT
        format( GETDATE(),'yyyyMMddHHmmss') +'Z' as 'udt:DateTimeString'                    
    INTO #tblCDSDeclarationAcceptanceDateTime

    SELECT * FROM #tblCDSDeclarationAcceptanceDateTime


    SELECT  
            '304' AS '@formatCode',
            Acc.[udt:DateTimeString]                        
    FROM    #tblCDSDeclarationAcceptanceDateTime Acc

    FOR XML PATH('AcceptanceDateTime'), TYPE

rollback tran
```

The error is as like below

```
Msg 6846, Level 16, State 4, Line 9
XML name space prefix 'udt' declaration is missing for FOR XML column name 'udt:DateTimeString'.
```

Anyone have an idea how I can include the "udt:" as the tag name.

Comment: Sorry No,I just tagged all versions.Currenlty I am using SQL server 2017

Comment: @ArunKumar But there is no such animal as "SQL server 2018". There is SQL Server 2017 and SQL Server 2019 (which is still CTP).

Comment: @andrey Nikolov...Again typo mistake from my part

Comment: You need to know *what actual namespace* `udt` is serving as a prefix for in your example. Prefixes *by themselves* carry no meaning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add "with xmlnamespaces" to your query. Try this:

```
begin tran
SELECT
    format( GETDATE(),'yyyyMMddHHmmss') +'Z' as 'udt:DateTimeString'                    
INTO #tblCDSDeclarationAcceptanceDateTime

SELECT * FROM #tblCDSDeclarationAcceptanceDateTime

;WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('udt' as udt) 
SELECT  
        '304' AS '@formatCode',
        Acc.[udt:DateTimeString]         
FROM    #tblCDSDeclarationAcceptanceDateTime Acc

FOR XML PATH('AcceptanceDateTime'), TYPE

rollback tran
```

Comment: `formatCode` is incorrectly embedded `AcceptanceDateTime`. Please run and see results.

Answer (score 0):

First,

```
<AcceptanceDateTime>
  <udt:DateTimeString formatCode="304">20161207010101Z</udt:DateTimeString>
</AcceptanceDateTime>
```

is not valid xml, since there is no namespace definition. That's why you get

> XML name space prefix 'udt' declaration is missing for FOR XML column
>   name 'udt:DateTimeString'.

To supply xml namespace definition, use WITH XMLNAMESPACES clause. But here is more - since `formatCode` attribute is embedded in `udt:DateTime` tag and prefix is ommited, attribute should use prefix specification as well. See following example:

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES('uri' AS udt)
SELECT *
FROM (VALUES (304, format(GETDATE(),'yyyyMMddHHmmss') +'Z')) T([udt:DateTimeString/@formatCode],[udt:DateTimeString])
FOR XML PATH('AcceptanceDateTime')
```

**Result**

```
<AcceptanceDateTime xmlns:udt="uri">
  <udt:DateTimeString formatCode="304">20181102094918Z</udt:DateTimeString>
</AcceptanceDateTime>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define `XMLNAMESPACES` first, in this case it's only `udt`

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('udt' as udt)
SELECT '304' AS '@formatCode',
    Acc.[udt:DateTimeString] 
FROM #tblCDSDeclarationAcceptanceDateTime Acc
for xml path('AcceptanceDateTime'),type
```

Which produces

```
<AcceptanceDateTime xmlns:udt="udt" formatCode="304">
    <udt:DateTimeString>20181102140727Z</udt:DateTimeString>
</AcceptanceDateTime>
```